# How can i retrieve documents from the firebase when i press on a certain button?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter development so this might be basic knowledge to you.
I have this application where I need the user to choose a retrieved tags from the database when they post

this is the tags I want to list them to the users where they can checkbox their desired tags [firebase collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5onf.png)

I tried to watch videos and read docs but there is always an error and I don't know what is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all documents in a collection by calling `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(YOUR_ID).snapshots()`

It will return a List of QuerySnapshots from which you can access the docs and their data.

Comment: and how can i list it in list view? i tried this and it didn't work StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Shopping').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('id'),

Comment: Just Map the list of documents and build for example a Listtile, then you can add them to the listviews children property

Comment: If you're using Streambuilder, you can map the data of the docs to a model, its probably easyier to use then